# Ошибка System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Mono_Posix_Stdlib_free C# Mono

Tags: c#, linux, .net, mono, posix

Пытаюсь работать с шиной i2c на Raspberry Pi. Нашел обертку для использования. При запуске вылетает ошибка System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Mono_Posix_Stdlib_free C# Mono. 
Обертка по ссылке [i2c wrapper](https://github.com/brookpatten/Mono.Linux.I2C)

```
  using Mono.Unix.Native;
  using Mono.Unix;

  [DllImport("libc.so.6", EntryPoint = "ioctl", SetLastError = true)]
    extern private static int ioctl(int fd, int request, byte x);

  byte[] bytes;
        using (var i2cBus = new I2CBus(bus))
        {
            var i2cDevice = new I2CDevice(i2cBus, 0x22);

            log.Debug($"{i2cDevice.ToString()} Device");

            System.Console.WriteLine($"{i2cDevice.Address} address");
            log.Debug($"{i2cDevice.Address} address");
            System.Console.WriteLine($"{i2cDevice.ReadByte(0x00)} Data");
            log.Debug($"{i2cDevice.ReadByte(0x00)} Data");

        }
```

Как только происходит вызов ReadByte (или любой другой метод из библиотеки) вываливается эта ошибка.
Вот метод чтения байт из библиотеки

```
 public unsafe byte ReadBytes(byte devAddr, byte regAddr, byte length, byte[] data, int offset=0, ushort timeout = 0)
    {
        if (length > 127)
            throw new IOException(_device + ": length > 127");

        //TODO: break this up so that we can await on all 3  native calls
        ChangeDevice(devAddr);

        //fixed(byte* p = &regAddr)
        {
            int ret = (int)Syscall.write(_fd, &regAddr, 1);
            if (ret != 1)
            {
                CheckAndThrowUnixIOException();
            }
        }

        int count;
        fixed (byte* p = &data[offset])
        {
            count = (int)Syscall.read(_fd, p, (ulong)length);
            if (count < 0)
            {
                CheckAndThrowUnixIOException();
            }
            else if (count != length)
            {
                throw new IOException(_device + ": read short: length = " + length + " > " + count);
            }
        }

        return (byte)count;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал скопировать библиотеку которая создается при билде (Mono.Posix.dll) и заменил в папке /usr/lib/mono/4.0-api / Не помогло. Куда дальше смотреть?

Comment: [Net Core не вариант](https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2017/05/08/using-net-core-2-to-read-from-an-i2c-device-connected-to-a-raspberry-pi-3-with-ubuntu-16-04/)? Думаю можно и под Mono запустить.

Comment: Да, я видел это. Кстати что-то оно мне постоянно читает только 255, но это  не суть. По поводу моей ошибки, я заменил пакет Mono.Posix 5.x.x на 4.0. Ошибка пропала, но теперь IOExeption вылетает, что-то связанно с ioctl при смене адреса i2c устройства. В `extern private static int ioctl(int fd, int request, byte x);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка ушла после даунгрейда **Mono.Posix с последней стабильной версии 5.х.х до 4.0**
Также в коде необходимо установить адрес по которому происходит обращение к I2C шине в самом ядре(насколько я правильно понял копаясь в исходниках i2c-dev, ioctl Mono.Posix и тд)

> public const int I2C_SLAVE = 0x0703;

если этот адрес изменить будет ошибка IO. Я перепутал адрес с адресом самого подключаемого устройства(чипа).
Все запустилось и удалось теперь работать с шиной.